# In kendo chart tooltip is not showing properly

Tags: kendo-ui

[image]I am working on kendo controls.I am having kendo stock chart in my application.I am providing tool-tip feature for chart.But it is not showing values,it showing values as "Undefined".When using the event which allows us to custom the tool-tips for a bar\line chart. The Data Item that is passed to the event is returned as Undefined . So, is there is property which I can be set that allows custom the tool-tip, even when their is a lot of pionts in a small area. Example: template: "#= dataItem.employeeName #".What is the problem in my chart code?

Comment: I am tried that one also But no result.And one more thing I have huge amount of data in my application.I have 500 data point but it was showing for oneday data .If I configured  Like this #= employeeName #  data is not apperaing

Comment: Would you mind showing some actual code? If so either edit your original question or -even better- use JSFiddler showing the effect.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5bchz/59/ here is the fiddle,this is the example code of my original code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have to use in the template definition `#= dataItem.<fieldName> #` for example: `Freight :#=dataItem.Freight# <br/>` since the structure received as `data` by the KendoUI `template` processor is `dataItem.<fieldName>`.

So your template should be:

```
template: "#OrderDate:#=dataItem.OrderDate# <br/>Freight :#=dataItem.Freight# <br/>ShipVia:#=dataItem.ShipVia# <br/> ShipCity:#= dataItem.ShipCity#"
```

**NOTE** As debugging trick, you might define as `template`:

```
template: "#console.log('data', data);#"
```

This executes the code enclosed by `#`. Kendo UI template manager defines as `data` the actual data that you have available in something like:

```
using(data) {
    // Template expanded code
};
```

This makes correct using `#= dataItem.ShipCity #` but does not prevent you from still using `data`. We take advantage of this for displaying on the browser console the `data` and the checking its structure.

Your modified JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/64/

Comment: Thank you onabai its working but Date format is displaying in GMT format.How to display time in normal format(which is displaying in grid)?

Comment: Hai, I got this error when i place the console log in my app .data 
Object
category: Wed Feb 06 2013 13:41:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
dataItem: 97
percentage: undefined
series: Object
value: 97
_proto_: Object
2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Time is not defined

Comment: Define `OrderDate` in the `template` as `OrderDate:#=kendo.toString(new Date(dataItem.OrderDate),'MM/dd/yyyy')# <br/>`. Updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/65/

Comment: Which browser are you using? It works for me in Chrome / OSX. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/67/

Comment: Thank you onabai.I am using Google chrome.It is working in local host,but in my application I put the code same as it is but still now tool-tip displaying as "undefined"

Comment: Doesn't make sense since in JSFiddle we also use a remote DataSource. Have you been able of debugging (`console.log`) what is being received as `data`?

Comment: I updated the image of my application once that.At the time of debugging I captured that image.Please once see that.

Comment: That capture does not correspond to the Fiddle! Did you realize that `data` structure is also different? Could you update Fiddle to be as close as possible to what you have in the server (bar chart)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27467/discussion-between-onabai-and-user2138545)

Answer (score 0):

Add **#debugger;#** keyword as **break point in kendo UI template** of javascript block.
Open your browser console. Browser automatically hits the break point.